# DBUnit doesn't reset sequences

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, junit, dbunit

I have a system with Spring + Maven + JPA (Hibernate). I use Junit and DBUnit.
I have an Entity with generated id: during tests it don't reset the sequence. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Why does the sequence need to be reset for your tests to be successful?

Comment: @Filip obviously you need to reset sequence in order to be able to provide a static number in your expected dataset. Without reseting the sequnce number is dynamic which make it hard to write tests.

Answer (score 3):

you can try the following:

```
    @Before
    public void resetSequence() {
      // run sql to reset the sequence.
      // for DB without functionality to reset sequences (eg. oracle) you can try dropping and re-creating the sequence
    }
```

the sequence will reset before every test.